# convert SQL to LINQ or imporve my query please

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to convert sql to lambda or LINQ but can't simplified yet,

I managed to do it two different lambda but i want it a single query.

SQL query is this :

```
  SELECT PamID, MAX (MaxAmount)
    FROM RebateTable
GROUP BY PamID
```

so far this is working but is there any better way.

```
var t = from r in RebateList
    group r by r.PamID;
var x = from y in t
    select new RebateMaxClass
    {
        PamId = y.Key,
        TotalSale = y.Max(s => s.MaxAmount)
    };
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can use `group r by r.PamID into y` instead.

Comment: I think you can try to use Linqer to convert SQL to LINQ http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this form:

```
RebateTable.GroupBy(r=>r.PamId).Select(s=>new RebateMaxClass
    {
        PamId = s.Key,
        TotalSale = s.Max(y => y.MaxAmount)
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for help NoImagination.

Answer (score 2):

The query look good. You could form a single query like this:

```
var t = from r in RebateList
        group r by r.PamId into y
        select new
        {
            PamId = y.Key,
            TotalSale = y.Max(s => s.MaxAmount)
        };
```

But this is not faster. The Query is extended and will ont be executed until is has to.

An alternative is forming the "new LinQ-Style":

```
var t2 = RebateList.GroupBy(g => g.PamId) // Do a Grouping
var t3 = t2.Select(s => new { PamId = s.Key, TotalSale = s.Max(m => m.MaxAmount) });
```

Comment: Thank you Kara, your answer is correct but NoImagination answer seems a bit better.. I wish i could select 2 answers as correct.

Comment: @AliAzra Jop - Perfect answer from Nolmagination. But keep in mind, that the executed code is the same. Splitting the query for better readability is sometimes a good thing.

Comment: Thank you .. I keep in mind, your new LinQ-Style answer is same like Nolmagination